# Rails Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am using rails 3.2.6 , ruby 1.8.7

I want add devise authentication in application..
I do following below mentioned in my app..

1. `gem 'devise'` add in Gemfile
2. after `rails g devise:install` in cmd prompt.
3. Add this line in `developement.rb`

   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }`
4. Add this line in `config/application.rb`

   `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
5. Finally, I run this cmd `rails g devise user`.
   I got this error.

   > SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
   >      This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
   >      provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
   >      cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
   >      future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

   If you know answer for this error. please let me know..

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate application token. It can be simply done by running:

```
rake secret
```

And add to `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`

```
AppName::Application.config.secret_token = 'CODE_HERE'
```

**EDIT**: Thanks [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967593/nick)

Comment: `rake secret` merely returns a new secret token.  He needs to add it to `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`: AppName::Application.config.secret_token = 'CODE_HERE'